# cellForRow(at: IndexPath) in swift 3 is acting funny in XCode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to recover a cell from a TableView using the method cellForRow(at: IndexPath) but the compiler doesn't seem to like this method because it won't let me call it :S

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf23z.jpg (Can't post images yet)

Here's the snippet of the code in question:

```
if let i = self.data.index(of: snapshot.value as! String) {

    self.data[i] = snapshot.value as! String

    self.tableView.cellForRow(at: i).textLabel!.text = "Modd"


    self.tableView.cellForRow(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)])!.textLabel!.text = "mod"
} 
else {

    print("Modified an item that wasn't in the data list")
}
```

How should I be calling the method if the compiler accepts neither of the two?

Comment: self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem with your second statement is that you add the indexPath that you create to an array.

Use the following code:

```
self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
```

Comment: Thanks!! Now what I don't understand is why this `self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)` takes it as an array just fine.

I took the code from the Firebase Realtime Database guide and it had that, so I assumed it was the way to do it

Comment: Look at the method signatures  - `deleteRows` - plural vs `cellForRow` - singular.  You can delete multiple rows at once, but you only retrieve a single row at a time

Comment: deleteRows is plural, thus deleting more than one row and therefor it takes in an array of rows to delete.  You will see deselectRow is singular, similar to cellForRow and thus take in the indexPath of one row only as argument.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for clarifying. I'm still bugged that the compiler error both told me it was expecting an 'Int' and that the value was of type 'IndexPath' and not '[IndexPath]'. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You were miles away from what the function expected, so it looks like the compiler gave its best guess that it was an array of Ints, but basically garbage in-garbage out

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
      let cell:UITableViewCell
      if let i = self.data.index(of: snapshot.value as! String) {

         self.data[i] = snapshot.value as! String

         cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

         cell.textLabel!.text = "Modd"
      }
      else {

         print("Modified an item that wasn't in the data list")
      }

      return cell == nil ? UITableViewCell() : cell

   }
```